# UISegmentedControl.noSegment stopped working with Xcode 11, iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13, xcode11

I've had two segmented controls stacked on top of each other, each with two options, so there's a 2x2 grid of filtering options for a search field.  This has worked fine, but I just updated to Xcode 11 and `UISegmentedControl.noSegment` has stopped working when I try to update it in response to user selection. However, it works when I set the initial value to `.noSegment` in the property observer. `isMomentary` is set to false. The outlets are all set up correctly. Is there some update to `UISegmentedControl` behavior I'm missing, or is this a bug?

New, incorrect behavior shown [here](https://gph.is/g/aeYdQ7W).

Current code that was working before, and stopped working after update:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var segmentedControlOne: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet private weak var segmentedControlTwo: UISegmentedControl! {
    didSet {
        // Start with no segment selected on this control. This works!
        segmentedControlTwo.selectedSegmentIndex = -1
    }
}

@IBAction private func oneIndexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    //Turn off selection on second control while first is selected
    segmentedControlTwo.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment

    let i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    if i == 0 {
        searchType = .users
    } else {
        searchType = .contributors
    }
}

@IBAction private func twoIndexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    //Turn off selection on first control while second is selected
    segmentedControlOne.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment

    let i = sender.selectedSegmentIndex
    if i == 0 {
        searchType = .articles
    } else {
        searchType = .categories
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for asking this question. I ran into the same issue, so was great to get some confirmation it wasn't just something I was missing.

While Apple hopefully fixes this bug soon, I implemented the following workaround by recreating the segments. This code sample is based on a `UISegmentedControl` with images as segments, you could of course implement the same approach for title strings:

```
public func resetSegmentedControl(_ control: UISegmentedControl) {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        // workaround: recreate the segments
        let numSegments = control.numberOfSegments
        let segmentImages = (0..<numSegments).compactMap { control.imageForSegment(at: $0) }
        control.removeAllSegments()
        for (index, image) in segmentImages.enumerated() {
            control.insertSegment(with: image, at: index, animated: false)
        }
    } else {
        // for earlier versions of iOS, just reset the selectedSegmentIndex
        control.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControl.noSegment
    }
}
```

There's a slight flicker when removing and re-inserting the segments, but for me that's preferable to the broken state.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @matt in the comment below, all that's needed is a call to `setNeedsLayout`,i.e.:

```
control.selectSegmentIndex = .noSegment
control.setNeedsLayout()
```

Comment: No need for this elaborate workaround. Just call `setNeedsLayout`.

Comment: I didn’t want to repeat my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58202246/341994