# iOS 13 UISegmentedControl inside UITableView caches previous selection

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, ios13

I have a screen with UITableView which displays one row per data element available, count of data element can be in hundreds. Depending on the data element type, each rows shows either an input field or segmented control. There is problem with the segmented control in iOS 13, when user taps first or second segment of a segmented control row on the top of the view and scrolls down, it auto select first segment for some random segmented control row in the subsequent scrolling view/page. It looks as if the control state is not refreshed.

Here is the code snippet of cellForRowAtIndexPath function where it creates the UISegmentedControl row.

```
QuestionOnTopTableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YesNoInputIdentifier"];
     if (!cell) {
        cell = [[QuestionOnTopTableViewCell alloc] initWithCellStyle:QuestionCellStyleYesNo reuseIdentifier:@"YesNoInputIdentifier"];
     }
     cell.titleLabel.text = row.title;
     cell.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = row.answer ? row.answer.boolValue : UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
```

Any one ran into this issue?

Note: This issue happens only on iOS13.

Comment: I think the problem is that UISegmentedControlNoSegment is not working on iOS 13. This is well documented in other stack overflow questions.

Comment: What @matt said. Here's another question addressing that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904625/specifying-uisegmentedcontrolnosegment-to-uisegmentedcontrols-selectedsegmentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system will only allocate enough cells to visually display, and then when one scrolls off it reuses it for the new cell scrolling in. As a result - when this happens it remembers the previous selection as you're seeing.

Not sure why this wasn't happening pre iOS 13 (it does look like your `cellForRowAt:` function should set the correct value if you're looking at the right `row` variable, but you should just be able to reset it by overriding the `UITableViewCell`s `prepareForReuse()` method.

## Swift

```
class QuestionOnTopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

     // stuffs

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = .noSegment
    }
}
```

## Obj-C

This should work for you:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
}
```

## Edit:

I actually did just see another question claiming `.noSegment` doesn't work anymore after a value has been set on iOS13/Xcode 11 builds: [UISegmentedControl.noSegment stopped working with Xcode 11, iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58067441/uisegmentedcontrol-nosegment-stopped-working-with-xcode-11-ios-13)

What you may need to do instead, unfortunately, is recreate a local version of the segmented control every time and overriding the control: `cell.segmentControl = myNewJustCreatedSegmentControl`

you can perhaps still do that in the `prepareForReuse` method

Comment: setting selectedSegmentIndex at the prepareForUse doesnt work, I am thinking about your second solution, about creating new control in the prepareforreuse, will it cause any performance problem? We have hundreds of such rows.

Comment: well if you wanted to optimize you could only recreate if you're trying to reset to `.noSegment` otherwise set the value on the old one. but for performance issues the number of rows won't matter (the only thing that will matter is the number of visible rows and how fast we're scrolling or how often we call `reloadData()`) Best way to know for sure is to try and see for yourself - you may be able to benchmark on Instruments as well